# Light weight URL rewriting on windows

Tags: windows, iis-7, url-rewriting

**Environment**
IIS7 on Windows server 2003.
Having to applications on two different application pools.

**Requirement**
Being able to direct a request to a specific application according to the parameters on the URL. Doing so under high load of requests.

**Current using**
 - [url-rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) - to change the port of the request.
 - [application-request-routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) - to allow the request to re-enter the IIS and change application pool.
This solution provide the logic I'm looking for but with a poor performance.

**Optimal**
If I could capture the request before it retching the IIS and rewrite it, using a light weight mechanism (Service? Driver?)

Comment: You must be using at least Windows Server 2008 if you are using IIS7 and application request routing. Although of course the ARR module will cause some overhead it is very unlikely that it is the bottleneck causing your performance problems. What kind of poor performance are we talking about? How many requests per second? What hardware?